# WebRTC "audioOutputLevel" value mean

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc

I read about audio level document on webrtc stats API site:

[Identifiers for WebRTC's Statistics API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc-stats/)

On this site, they describe AudioLevel value between 0..1.
When I get stats of audio stream and print to console. The result is below:

```
▿ 29 key/value pairs
 ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "ssrc"
    - value: "2726297394"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googDecodingPLC"
    - value: "18"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googSecondaryDecodedRate"
    - value: "0"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googDecodingCTN"
    - value: "911"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googJitterReceived"
    - value: "5"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "transportId"
    - value: "Channel-audio-1"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googExpandRate"
    - value: "0.0194092"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "packetsReceived"
    - value: "439"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "audioOutputLevel"
    - value: "28025"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googDecodingMuted"
    - value: "43"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googDecodingPLCCNG"
    - value: "44"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "totalSamplesDuration"
    - value: "9.11"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googPreemptiveExpandRate"
    - value: "0.0101318"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googSpeechExpandRate"
    - value: "0.0194092"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "packetsLost"
    - value: "1"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googPreferredJitterBufferMs"
    - value: "120"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googDecodingCTSG"
    - value: "0"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googCurrentDelayMs"
    - value: "158"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googCaptureStartNtpTimeMs"
    - value: "0"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "mediaType"
    - value: "audio"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "bytesReceived"
    - value: "41628"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googCodecName"
    - value: "opus"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googDecodingCNG"
    - value: "0"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "totalAudioEnergy"
    - value: "3.47756"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googJitterBufferMs"
    - value: "120"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googSecondaryDiscardedRate"
    - value: "0"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googAccelerateRate"
    - value: "0.00354004"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googDecodingNormal"
    - value: "849"
  ▿ (2 elements)
    - key: "googTrackId"
    - value: "OCVMXiq8"
```

I didn't find a key "audioLevel" as the document described, but the "audioOutputLevel" found.
Then, what is this value mean or can it transform to "audioLevel" value as the article above

---

UPDATE
Here is sample code i use to get Stats

```
for receive in (self.client!.peerConnection!.receivers) {
                self.client!.peerConnection!.stats(for: receive.track!, statsOutputLevel: .debug, completionHandler: { reports in
                    for report in reports {
                        print("-------- report id \(report.reportId) in time \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
                        dump(report.values)
                        print("-----------------------------------------")
                    }

                })
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the "legacy" getStats API, i.e. you call

```
pc.getStats(function(res) {
  // show result
})
```

in which this is called aduioOutputLevel. If you use

```
pc.getStats().then(function(stats) {
  // show result
})
```

it should show up as audioLevel.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/ shows a full example.

Comment: I use WebRTC in iOS [https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleWebRTC). i check method then getStats in PeerConnection has only this way.

Comment: divide the audioOutputLevel by 32768 then, that should be the equivalent.

Comment: do you have any document to prove your way?